# Issue while trying to connect to BigQuery in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

node version: v18.12.1
@google-cloud/bigquery version: v6.0.3

I am using a service account to to connect to bigQuery, then trying to run a simple query. Query is working fine on google console but for some reason I am facing issues while running it with nodejs

```
const authFile = require("./enums/authFile.json");
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");

const queryDb = new BigQuery({
    keyFilename: authFile,
    projectId: "projectId"
  });

  const result = await queryDb.createDataset("new_1datasetId", { location: "US" });
```

I am  getting this error for every kind of query I try to run. Even when I  try to create a queryJob with

> ```
> const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
> ```

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
    at Object.resolve (node:path:1098:7)
    at GoogleAuth.getClient (/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:633:39)
    at GoogleAuth.authorizeRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:679:35)
    at authorizeRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:439:47)
    at prepareRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:444:25)
    at BigQuery.makeAuthenticatedRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:455:13)
    at BigQuery.request_ (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service.js:148:18)
    at BigQuery.request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service.js:159:36)
    at BigQuery.createDataset (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/build/src/bigquery.js:902:14)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:57:28
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at BigQuery.wrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:42:16)
    at checkAlert (/usr/src/app/src/helpers/echo.js:131:34)
    at /usr/src/app/src/helpers/echo.js:118:9 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `authFile` is a module. The constructor expects a [path to the file itself](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/74a9fffed6b8fb3cdb6e90a26960586baed40f3b/src/auth/googleauth.ts#L84).

```js
const queryDb = new BigQuery({
  keyFilename: "./enums/authFile.json",
  projectId: "projectId"
});
```

Comment: Yes it's working. If there a way to pass json or jsObject here as I would prefer to directly fetch service file from db as json.

Comment: I suppose you could pull it from the db and write it to an in-memory file using [memory-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-fs).